# Core image module not found

Tags: 7, drush, media

Some how it seems like the `core image module` is missing from the module list.

Here is the screenshot of the module list:

[image]

Also I tried fetching the list using drush.

```
$ drush pml | grep image
 Image                                Image Attach (image_attach)                                                          Module  Not installed  7.x-1.x-dev          
 Image                                Image Gallery (image_gallery)                                                        Module  Not installed  7.x-1.x-dev          
 Image                                Image Import (image_import)                                                          Module  Not installed  7.x-1.x-dev          
 Image                                Image legacy (image_legacy)                                                          Module  Not installed  7.x-1.x-dev          
 Image                                ImageMagick Advanced Options (image_im_advanced)                                     Module  Not installed  7.x-1.x-dev          
 ImageAPI                             ImageAPI (imageapi)                                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.x-dev          
 ImageAPI                             ImageAPI GD2 (imageapi_gd)                                                           Module  Enabled        7.x-1.x-dev          
 ImageAPI                             ImageAPI ImageMagick (imageapi_imagemagick)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.x-dev          
 Other                                Image crop (imagefield_crop)                                                         Module  Not installed  7.x-1.1              
 Spam control                         Image CAPTCHA (image_captcha)                                                        Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0-beta2
```

But the list shows up on the database system table. All the images on my site are not showing up because of this.

I fixed this issue by manual enabling the module from the database and also had to set `bootstrap = 1` for it work properly, without it won't work.

so for image row I have to make this changes on system table.

`status = 1 and bootstrap = 1`

This is bit weird but some how the image module gets disable after some time ( days ). Not sure what is causing it. Every time I have this issue, I have to go to database and make the same changes as above. Can some one guide me what might be causing this issue or how do I debug this.

Note: this is multi site installation.

> Update: Rregistry rebuild using `drush rr` also fixes the issue, but
>   doesn't seem to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Missing Image module from the list suggest that it disappeared somehow from the `system` table which have the list of all modules.

To confirm that, double check that directly using the query, e.g.:

```
drush sqlq "SELECT * FROM system WHERE name='image'"
```

It's difficult to answer what causing that without actually debugging it. It depends what kind of modules you've installed, custom code and the environment it-self (e.g. caching).

To track the problem, you can try:

- temporary disable external caches (memcached/redis),
- temporary disable PHP caches (OPCache/APC/XCache/eAccelerator) or its settings which could interfere with Drupal internals,
- disable any automated QA testing (such as Simpletests or Selenium) for affected environment,
- disable useless non-stable modules,
- temporary disable further modules which you can,
- check if this is specific to environment (dev, stage, live),
- if happens on all, could be some bug in the code, so follow the section below.

#### Debugging

This could be a tricky part to find out, so you probably need some tricky tools to debug it.

Here are my ideas:

- watch the module lists and check when it's missing:

  ```
  watch 'drush pml | grep -w image || echo Missing'
  ```

  for example by sending your-self e-mail with the recent logs:

  ```
  watch 'drush pml | grep -w image || { drush watchdog-show | mail -s missing-image drupal@niepodam.pl && killall watch; } '
  ```
- run debuggers attached to MySQL which monitor everything to do with`system` table or `image` entry (note: it could be overwhelming for the system):

  ```
  sudo strace -e recvfrom -s999 -fp $(pgrep mysqld) | grep -w image >> sql.log
  ```
- run debuggers attached to PHP:

  ```
  sudo strace -e sendto -s999 -fp $(pgrep -fn php) 2>&1 | egrep "system|image" >> php.log
  ```

  Or simply enable log queries in MySQL configuration file.

  Above is more useful if you've Devel installed, so there is an option to prepend a function name before the query (so you know exactly which function caused it).
- install [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and enable tracing for the part which you suspect the most by adding `xdebug_start_trace();` and `xdebug_stop_trace();` in appropriate places (see sample [ini](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) config), suggested places would be:

  - `system_list()`
  - `system_list_reset()`

  then analyse the trace files.